# I can't seem to get Bootstrap Carousel to work locally, but it works on codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a bootstrap carousel working on my site, and it shows collapsed, but instead of going to the next slide, it just "jumps" down a little bit.

Here is my header which might be out of order:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="javascript"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-all-testing.umd.dev.js" type="javascript"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And here is the HTML for the carousel that I'm having trouble with:

```
  <div class="carousel slide" id="spinner" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active" data-target="#spinner" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#spinner" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#spinner" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#spinner" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true">
  </span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#spinner" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true">
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span></span></a>
    </div>
```

As a note, I've gotten this to work on Codepen, but it doesn't run on the machine I'm coding on.

[Carousel on Codepen](http://codepen.io/christopherrutherford/pen/NAVoaG)

I'm not concerned with the look of the Carousel on codepen, just the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 3 has some compatibility issues with bootstrap 3. Your codepen is using jquery 2.2.4. Switch your jQuery version to 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

It works with previous version of jQuery, not the version 3.x.

The snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel slide" id="spinner" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#spinner" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#spinner" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#spinner" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#spinner" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true">
  </span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#spinner" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true">
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes sense! I wasn't aware of the issues. I'll have to note that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link in your head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```